# Car eletronic mirrior controller is not working

Tags: wing-mirrors

Car is Hyundai coupe 2006.

There is a direction pad to control electronic left and right wing mirrors i.e. move them up, down, left and right.

Everything is working fine however it seems to me the left button is not working when pressed for either wing mirror.

What is the likely cause for this, can I repair it diy?

If mechanic is recommended, is this a small, medium or big job?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are comfortable to remove the door panel to access the underside of that area, the job becomes DIY. You can purchase panel tools inexpensively online or at local stores. Even [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=auto%20door%20panel%20tool&cat_id=0) carries them, although I didn't check for local stock.

[image: door panel removal tools]

You can expect to find plastic barbed "rivet" type parts holding the door panel to the metal frame of the door. Once you've popped enough free, you may be able to access the mirror control without removing the entire panel. Use caution to avoid pulling control wiring in such a way as to damage it.

You'll also find that all of the wiring has connectors that can be separated to allow panel removal. Press the release tab on the connector when pulling and avoid pulling on the wires. Apply force to the connector directly.

Once you have the panel off, you can see how the controller is attached. The photos on eBay show a pair of tabs with holes that might be bolt or screw locations.

eBay has used controllers from ten to twenty dollars, not particularly expensive.

If you have a shop perform this task, it will be much more expensive, as the door removal can be time consuming and they will use new parts at new part prices. Consider that a body shop is probably going to be more adept at panel removal and replacement.

To provide additional confidence for the DIY aspect, pop into Google and use "door panel removal 2006 Hyundai Coupe." Many YouTube results to provide some insight. One of them is the window motor replacement which starts with the panel removal.

If you know which end of the screwdriver draws blood, you probably can perform this task.

Comment: Might I be able to repair the current controller rather than replace it? Is it definately the controller or could it be a circuit issue or something else?  thanks

Comment: until you open it up, you won't know what has to be corrected. The fact that the other buttons work and this one does not, and does not for both sides, points to the controller being the problem. If fate is on your side, you could discover that the common connector for the left mirror has fallen off and needs only to be replaced.